# How check other property use custom rule in fluent validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

Let's say there is a class and I need to check the value of property 1 against the value of property 2 so that it can be reused. I don't understand how you can pass the value of 2 properties to a custom validation rule of 1 property using fluent validation

I have class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }  
    public string Property2 {get; set; }     
    public string Property3 { get; set; } 
}
```

and validato class

```
public class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(мyClass => мyClass.Property1).Property1();
    }
}
```

and custom rule

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string>
    Property1<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotNull()
                          .NotEmpty()
                          .Length(12)
    }
```

I want the rule

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string>

    Property1<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.Custom((x, c) => {
        if(x.Property2== "qwerty")
         if(x.Property1=="q")
          context.AddFailure("")
        });
    }
```

How can i pass property value of Property2 to Property1 property check?

Edit1
I want this check to be used on other classes

I just want to thank you for your reply.
So I decided not only to look at the answers, but also to ask my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [custom validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html). To quote an example from the docs...

```cs
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
  public PersonValidator() {
   RuleFor(x => x.Pets).Custom((list, context) => {
     if(list.Count > 10) {
       context.AddFailure("The list must contain 10 items or fewer");
     }
   });
  }
}
```

The `context` gives you access to the whole object being validated, so you can get at any other properties you want.

Comment: I probably didn't specify((
whether it is possible to make that these check was for many classes?

Comment: @AlekseyK Not clear what you mean. Maybe you can update your question to explain.

Comment: You helped a lot. Can you suggest how this check can be reused for other classes that have the same fields?

Comment: Well, if your other classes have properties of the same type and name, then you can have them all inherit a common interface. Then you can push the validation logic into a static method that take a parameter of the interface type.